# Can I claim my years of freelance before my degree as job experience?

Tags: work-experience, freelancing, hiring

I completed my 4 years bachelor degree in engineering in 9 years. In this extended duration I was working freelance designing for different construction companies. In fact, I probably was making more money than my peers who got jobs after completing graduation in 4 years. Now I have acquired a degree and have a design and software experience from my freelance work.

How can I convince my potential recruiters that I at least have 3-4 years of countable experience through my freelance work?

Comment: Write this. In better English. And with capital letters.

Comment: You should claim all experience in the relevant field you're applying for. It is up to the company to determine how relevant or useful that experience is.

Comment: **Remember not to accept an answer too quickly!** [You might want to wait 24 to 48 hours before accepting to give other people a chance to give you a better answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/260382). A question with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention as one without an accepted answer.

Comment: I think this question is basically answered here - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/how-can-freelance-work-count-towards-years-of-experience-on-resume-online-l
If you studied for 4-5 years and simultaneously did full-time freelance work which adds up to 3-4 years of experience, I think it counts but the real question is how to present this in a suitable way, or to explain it in a simple way, since you were studying at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

By listing each of your projects in your résumé with dates, client and your primary responsibilities. Except for the conditions in the work contract, a freelance job is just like a regular job.

Comment: @DonaldBlake No, I can not tell you this, because contrary to popular believe not all recruiters are perfect clones of each other. Each one has their own criteria by which they judge applicants. Also, not fully fulfilling every single requirement in the job posting does not necessarily mean that your application will go to the garbage bin right away.

Comment: @Philipp I'm sure they're still part of some sort of [Evil Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Empire) though.